# 'NaTType' object has no attribute 'isna'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column 'Var' in the following Pandas DataFrame based on values from the other columns. I am encountering issues when dealing with the `NaN`, `NaT`.

**Data:**
( Used `apply(pd.to_datetime)` on the `Date` columns at a previous step)

| Date | C | A | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-12-13 | 1233.0 | N | 9 |
| NaT | NaN | N | 5 |
| 2007-09-24 | 49.0 | N | 14 |

**Code:**

```
def program(Flat):
    if Flat['A'] == 'N' :
        return 0
    elif Flat['Date'].isna() :
        return Flat['Age'] + 1
    elif Flat['C'] < 365 :
        return 1
    elif Flat['C'] >= 365 :
        return math.floor((Flat['C'])/365.25) + 1

Flat['Var'] = Flat.apply(program, axis=1)
```

> Error: AttributeError: 'NaTType' object has no attribute 'isna'

Tried running through Anaconda & Python. All same error.
Pandas version is 1.3.3.

What is the correct way to detect the `NaT` type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"NaT" (for date/time types) and "NaN" are not the same.  However, you can use the "isnull" function for both types:

```
    elif pd.isnull(Flat['Data']):
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried but still same problem. 'AttributeError: 'NaTType' object has no attribute 'isnull'

Comment: My mistake.  It's a function to which you pass a value, not an attribute of the type.  I fixed it.

Comment: Amazing! thanks! So the pd.isnull() reads the value through the dataframe Flat['Data'] in this case?

Comment: Well, `Flat['Data']` returns an object.  It's either a datetime object or a NaTType object.  The global `isnull` function can tell the difference between them.